# Setting external IP address in google cloud to a static address i have reserved

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I recently started working with google cloud and built a node app to automatically deploy instances based on an image I have setup.

The script works well, the only issue I am running into is that I cannot seem to assign my static IP address I reserved using my config, I am new at node and google cloud, and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

any help or guidance at all would be much appreciated

my config looks like:

```
const config = {
        machineType: 'e2-micro',
        http:true,
        https:true,
        networkInterfaces: [
            {
            accessConfigs: [
                {
                  type: 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT',
                  name: 'External NAT',
                  natIP: '0.0.0.0',// this is an ip address that is passed into this as a variable in that format(it is not a scope issue)
                  setPublicPtr: false,
                  networkTier: 'PREMIUM', //ip address is reserved using this network tier as well
                }
              ],
              
 
      kind: 'compute#networkInterface'

      }],
        
        
        disks: [
          {
            boot: true,
            initializeParams: {
              sourceImage:
                'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects' +
                '/myproject/global/images/devimage'
            }
          }
        ],
        metadata: {
           
            items: [
              {
                key: 'startup-script',
                value: 'sudo node index.js'
              }
            ],
            kind: 'compute#metadata'
          },
        
        };
```

Comment: Can you share more about your architecture? Did you deploy on Compute Engine? Direct on internet, or behind a load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as of now, there are particularly no means to assign a static IP to an **existing** Compute Engine instance via the [Google API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/index.html).

In order to do so for an existing Compute Engine instance you would need to utilize either the [Google Cloud console or the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign).

However to assign a static IP to a new Compute Engine instance, you indeed would be able to do so via the API through a request similar to the following:

```
{
"name": "INSTANCE_NAME",
  "machineType": "zones/ZONE/machineTypes/MACHINE_TYPE",
  "networkInterfaces": [{
    "accessConfigs": [{
      "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
      "name": "External NAT",
      "natIP": "IP_ADDRESS"
     }],
    "network": "global/networks/default"
  }],
  "disks": [{
     "autoDelete": "true",
     "boot": "true",
     "type": "PERSISTENT",
     "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/v20150818"
     }
   }]
 }
```

In this case it is possible that the name of the instance was not provided, when creating a new instance and assigning the IP address.